# Custom NavigationBarButton has no controller on iOS 12 and below, iOS 13 is working

Tags: ios, swift, controller, uikit, navigationbar

I'm trying to use a CustomView with it's own ViewController as right NavigationBar (barbuttonitem). This view needs to be updated in dependency of an app status. The view is implemented like this:

```
private func addUploadStatusToNavigationController() {        
        cloudView = UploadStatusViewController<UploadStatusNavigationView>()

        let tgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cloudViewTapped))
        cloudView.customView.addGestureRecognizer(tgr)

        let cloudViewButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cloudView.customView)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cloudViewButton

        cloudView.setStatus(status: uploadStatusService.getStatus())

        if let btn = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView {
            btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width ?? 0) * 0.6, height: 44)
        }

        uploadStatusService.delegate = self
    }
```

This method is called in viewWillAppear.

Everything works fine with iOS 13 until I open an alert by tapping the view tab. If I close it again, the view loses its own controller - UploadStatusViewController - (at least in the ViewDebugger). Status updates running through this controller still work fine. Taps are no longer recognized.

With iOS 12 no taps are detected, not even the first one.

Presenting the alert looks like this:

```
private func askUserToStop() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "OneDrive", message: "BackupPopup.Cancel.Message".localized, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Button_Title_Cancel".localized, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action1)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

If I push a new controller onto the NavigationStack and navigate back again, the GestureRecognizer only works once again (iOS13).
I actually expect the TapGestureRecognizer to be preserved beyond the presenting of the popup and to work under iOS 12 as well.

I'm afraid I have no idea what else to try.

Edit:

Summarized:

- iOS 12: No action on tap, no UploadStatusViewController behind the View in ViewDebugger
- iOS 13: Action just on first tap, UploadStatusViewController gets removed in ViewDebugger after first tap.
- iOS 12 and 13: Other actions from the UploadStatusViewController like updating it's customView working fine.